# Как отследить нажатие на определенную картинку?

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть двумерный массив, состоящий из `PictureBox`: `PictureBox[,] heroesImages = new PictureBox[FIGURES_NUMBER / 20, FIGURES_NUMBER / 10];`, созданных программно и размещенных на панели. 
Как постоянно отслеживать нажатие мышкой на любую из картинок? Можно ли проверять любое нажатие в пределах формы, а потом выяснить является ли точка нажатия картинкой из этого массива?

```
public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Draw_Heroes(FIGURES_NUMBER / 20, FIGURES_NUMBER / 10);

    int _i, _j;

    for (int i = 0; i < FIGURES_NUMBER / 20; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < FIGURES_NUMBER / 10; j++)
        {

            _i = i;
            _j = j;

            heroesImages[i, j].MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(Hero_Click);

            void Hero_Click(object s, MouseEventArgs ev)
            {
                heroesImages[_i, _j].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: У вас в коде проблема с замыканием. Исправите ее и все будет работать как надо

Comment: @АндрейNOP, дело в том, что я не знаю как отслеживать абсолютно любое нажатие

Comment: Ну так вы же написали подписчик на событие

Comment: @АндрейNOP Цикл не начинается заново при новом нажатии или это и есть проблема в замыкании?

Comment: Переменные `i` и `j` уже изменились к тому моменту, как произошло нажатие — это проблема в замыкании. Попробуйте перед подпиской сохранить их в локальные переменные: `int _i = i, _j = j;` и в методе `Hero_Click` использовать именно `_i` и `_j`

Comment: @АндрейNOP это не решило проблему. Выделяется не нужная картинка, а, которая находится на последенем месте в массиве

Comment: Значит вы сделали что-то не так. Приведите измененный код в вопросе.

Comment: @АндрейNOP если я правильно понимаю, то этот цикл используется только один раз, при запуске программы

Comment: Разве я вам сказал так сделать? Я вам написал: "сохранить их в **локальные** переменные". Это важно!

Comment: Да, цикл запускается только один раз при запуске.

Comment: @АндрейNOP действительно все работает теперь, спасибо. Можете рассказать поподробней почему так происходит? Или что почитать хотя бы

Comment: Читайте базовую литературу по C#, там есть про это. Кратко — в вопросе-дубликате.